# Universal Docking Station with Dell

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, docking-station, displaylink

I have Dell XPS 17 9700, with Windows 10 Professional, and I connected it to a universal docking station called [Targus Dock177](https://ca.targus.com/products/universal-usb-3-0-dv4k-docking-station-with-power-dock177usz) which is compatible with **DisplayLink**.
It automatically detected the docking station and recognize all devices connected to it (two monitors, mouse, headphone....)
The Dell and docking station worked fine and smoothly for more than three months.
Dell detected automatically the Targus and monitors and connected them using "**DisplayLink**" driver

But suddenly today (12th January 2021) it doesn't recognize the monitors anymore.
Mouse and headphone still working, but the monitors are not working.

if you check the devices with "**Device Manager**" you will see the two monitors under "Display Adapters" being faulty and has errors (two of them), and the error message is:

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems.
> (Code 43)

[image]

I tried many things:

1. restart the PC
2. disabled the drivers and re-enable them
3. uninstall the drivers and restart again and install them
4. update the drivers (which they are up-to-date with displaylink drivers)

Every time I do that, it will go into a process that takes 2 minutes of flashing the monitors and popup of the taskbars, and at the end of two minutes it will just freeze the two monitors and only the laptop monitor works and only the laptop monitor get recognized, and the two monitors are not recognized.

When I try to detect the monitors I don't see them , just the laptop monitor.

When I check my Windows Update History I don't see any update recently. The latest update was on 20th December 2020. I force today this update:

[2021-01 Windows accumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4598242/windows-10-update-kb4598242) with no change on recognizing the monitors

This is my version of Windows 10

[image]

Comment: Did you update to 20H2 ? We have hit the same issue with it.

Comment: @EugenRieck No. I updated my post and added my windows 10 version

Comment: @GhassanKarwchan - You can essentially be on 20H2 through an update.  Can you [edit] your question to include `View update history` within Windows Update?

Comment: @Ramhound : 
When I go to windows update I can see there is an option to upgrade to 20H2, which I didn't proceed with it.
So I am assuming I am not on 20H2.
Anyway, I will add my windows update history

Comment: I would suggest installing [KB4598242](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4598242) due to changes it brought to the security of external devices.

Comment: @Ramhound I did, and it didn't help

Comment: @Ramhound I don't believe that's how 20H2 works. 20H2 uses an "enablement package" in the same say 1909 did. The files for the patch can be in place and staged but not actually in use. A computer with 20H2 staged (build 2004 with the October cumulative update installed) is still only 2004 and does not have any 20H2 features (or bugs) until the 20H2 enablement package is loaded to make the switch effective.

Comment: @music2myear - I actually know how it works.  It’s just difficult to explain the enablement package in a comment.

Comment: Appreciate your help everyone. the solution was very silly. I share it down. appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ramhound perhaps I misread but it seemed you were saying 20H2 caused these issues and when OP noted they were on 2004 you were trying to say they may "actually" be in 20H2 when they aren't. But that isn't the case. Having the files doesn't mean you have the version, which was the point of explaining the enablement package.

Comment: Having only extensively researched the enablement patch but never using it, I don’t know what version is actually reported after it’s installed, but it’s extremely likely that both 2004 and 20H2 would have the same bug.  Since it was a hardware issue solve by the greatest button of all time ONOFF it’s all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time of try and error, I found the solution and it is very silly.

I switched off the docking unit for 10 seconds, and switch it on again, and everything is back to normal.

I am sorry if this not really a technical answer, but I thought I will share it in case someone had the same issue.

I was trying to disconnect and reconnect the monitors and then I found it was one of the monitor port that is causing the problem.

So, I switched off the docking unit for a while and reconnect it again, and it just work as before.

I don't know what the cause but it could be some statics electricity or something.

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: These docks are computers. Sometimes they need to be powered off and back on.